# Format HTML code in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

When working with Java, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> formats your highlighted code. Is there such a command when working with non-Java files like HTML? The same command doesn't work with HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> for Formatting HTML files.

Comment: Thanks a lot. How about formatting groovy server pages(.gsp)

Comment: See Official link  [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-style-gsp.html)

Answer (score 9):

In Ultimate edition same keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) works for HTML as well. I suppose, community Edition doesn't support it out of the box.

Check settings: `Settings -> Editor -> Code Style -> HTML` (If it is not present, try to install some plugins for HTML support)

Answer (score 3):

For Mac

> Use <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> for Formatting HTML files.

You can check/customize it using:
<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> for a search for Reformat Code.